# Deleting a second XNA Game template

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, templates, xna, xna-4.0

I had been having errors relating to missing references for an XNA Game I was working on and discovered when I attempted to create a new project that I have two XNA Game templates, one with all the references I need, and one with some missing.  I actually have two templates for the Windows, XBox 360, and Content Projects.  The Windows phone templates are all working as they should.  Is there any way I can delete these broken templates?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here's where you can find your installed XNA Game templates:

[image]

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\XNA Game Studio 4.0\ProjectTemplates\XNA Game Studio 4.0
```

Delete any templates that you don't want. (Just be careful not to delete any that you do want or you might have to reinstall XNA Game Studio to get them back).